Can a para-NP-Complete problem be $\Sigma^P_2$-Complete in its non-parameterized version?
I have a problem which (I think) have proven to be para-NP-Complete concerning some parameter $k$.
However, I am certainly sure that the non-parameterized version of this problem is $\Sigma^P_2$-Complete. Is this possible? (assuming standard complexity assumptions) Or do I have a mistake in the parameterized complexity result?

If we are free to choose the parameter, the parametrized version of a problem can be arbitrarily easier. Whether your particular parameter has this property depends on the specific problem and parameter.
